# Deriving the formula of number of geometrical isomers in symmetric polyenes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, chemistry

For example, if we take the case of Hexa-2.4-diene we have 3 isomers which will have cis-cis, trans-trans and cis-trans arrangements at the two double bonds present. The aim is to get a formula for the number of geometrical isomers of a symmetric polyene with n double bonds, when n is odd and when it is even.

I observed that cis-trans and trans-cis would mean the same thing for two double bonds at same position from the two sides. When I try to think what's going to happen after this it just gets too overwhelming because I think that one would have to consider a lot of cases.

I also read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521886/short-trick-for-finding-geometrical-isomers) post but it does not seem to help.

The answer is-

1. $2^{n-1}+2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ ; when $n$ is odd.
2. $2^{n-1}+2^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$ ; when $n$ is even.